# Why am I not able to run ng serve inside workspace?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, serve

So basically if I type the command "ng serve" inside the terminal and inside the right workspace. (I also tried "sudo ng serve") I get the following error for some reason : Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

Can someone help me please?!

Comment: it is new project or you update it from old version to latest or some other version.

Comment: Are you sure you are in an actual workspace, i.e. does `package.json` exist in that folder?

Comment: @CherryDT yes I am sure. I am in an actual workspace. And it does contain a package.json......

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant `angular.json`. Make sure you are in the same directory as `angular.json` (not some subdirectory) and also that there is no syntax error in the file.

Comment: @CherryDT I have on the root of my project the angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the angular.json file in your project. Run `ng serve` in **that** folder.

Answer (score 1):

i got this error when i typed `ng new projectName` in the terminal to start a new project and i solve it just by deleting all the directories and files of the old project. It works fine after that.
PS: my error was "This command is not available when running the Angular CLI inside a workspace." not outside a workspace.